# Macro inserted via \everypar in \obeylines context doesn't see some commands

Tags: tables, tex-core, multicol

I have the following code which works as expected except, as noted in the code, when a macro begins a line of the `xltabular` being built:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487572/obeylines-and-gappto-from-etoolbox
%% Collect the body of the xltabular in \tabbody:
\begingroup
    \lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{%
\endgroup
    \def\tabline#1~{%
        \xappto{\tabbody}{\unexpanded{#1\\\hline}}~
    }
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{listit}{}{%
    \gdef\tabbody{}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \raggedcolumns
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \col@number\@ne
            \mathchardef\LT@end@pen=0 %
            \begingroup
                \offinterlineskip
                \everypar={\tabline}
                \obeylines
}{%
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\explain}{}{%
            \endgroup
            \vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{X}
                \hline\hline
                \tabbody
                \hline
            \end{xltabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{listit}
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt
\bfseries See Note
ut labore
et dolore
magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad
\explain

Note: \verb+\bfseries+ by itself is ignored. \verb+\textbf{See Note}+ produces \verb+Extra \fi+ error.
\end{listit}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\leavevmode\bfseries See Note` produces the expected output. Why is this necessary?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Diagnosis

The problem is that the lines of your `\tabbody` are collected by the `\tabline` macro, which is inserted by `\everypar`. However, the `\everypar` tokens are only inserted when a paragraph starts, and `\bfseries` used in vertical mode doesn't cause TeX to start a paragraph (i.e., to switch to horizontal mode). So, when one of the special lines designed to be read by `\tabline` starts with `\bfseries`, TeX is still in vertical mode when it finds the `\bfseries` (this is right after an end-of-line has been turned into `\par`). It expands it, and *only later* when a 〈horizontal command〉<sup>1</sup> causes a switch to horizontal mode, it inserts `\tabline` which will collect the rest of the line. But when this happens, it is too late, the `\bfseries` has already been fully expanded and digested, it is not grabbed as part of the `#1` by the inserted `\tabline`.

Example: suppose that TeX is collecting these lines:

```latex
tempor incididunt
\bfseries See Note
```

`tempor incididunt` is the first argument of the `\tabline` macro that was inserted by means of `\everypar` when the paragraph was started with the `t` from `tempor incididunt` (`t` is a 〈letter〉 and therefore a 〈horizontal command〉; when TeX finds it in vertical mode, it switches to horizontal mode to start a new paragraph). So, the expansion of this `\tabline` consumed `tempor incididunt•` from the input stream, where `•` represents an active end-of-line character (it is active because `\obeylines` was used above). After these tokens have been removed from the input stream, the replacement text of `\tabline` is inserted, with `tempor incididunt` substituted for `#1`:

```latex
\xappto{\tabbody}{\unexpanded{tempor incididunt\\\hline}}•
```

Once `\xappto` has been fully processed, TeX finds the • that was just inserted, which has been made `\let`-equivalent to `\par` by `\obeylines`:

```latex
\obeylines:
macro:->\catcode `\^^M\active \let ^^M\par
```

Therefore, when this • token is digested, TeX ends the paragraph and switches to vertical mode. The next token from the input stream is `\bfseries`. This is a macro, therefore it is expanded. I pass on the details of its expansion (`\protect\bfseries` [where the second `\bfseries` has a space at the end of its name, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88007/73317)). What is important is that this `\bfseries` doesn't start a new paragraph (its expansion doesn't contain any 〈horizontal command〉). This only happens when TeX digests the `S` from `See Note`, i.e., after `\bfseries` has been fully processed. At this point, TeX switches to horizontal mode because the `S` is a 〈horizontal command〉; it inserts the indentation box (invisible here because `\parindent` is `0pt`), then the tokens stored in `\everypar`, in your case a single `\tabline`, and resumes normal processing of the input stream. The just-inserted `\tabline` token is expanded, this grabs `See Note` as the first argument (you see, `\bfseries` isn't present in this argument, it is already behind us), consumes the active end-of-line character that follows (because it is part of the 〈parameter text〉 of the macro), then the replacement text is inserted with `See Note` substituted for `#1`:

```latex
\xappto{\tabbody}{\unexpanded{See Note\\\hline}}•
```

(note that this `\xappto` call doesn't append the `\bfseries` to `\tabbody`, it has definitely been lost for `\tabbody`) and the process goes on, as we just explained.

## Proposed solution

I propose not to rely on `\everypar`. Rather, we can make the end-of-line character active in the innermost group of your `listit` environment definition and redefine the active end-of-line character to be `\let`-equal to `\tabline` (see my `\listit@obeylines` macro). This way, every end-of-line character in the special portion becomes equivalent to a `\tabline` token and is expanded right before the next line. This way, its `#1` grabs everything until the following end-of-line, and thus no command is lost.

This method even allows you to have `\par` tokens among the text that is collected in `\tabbody` (see `Paragraph break here:\par But...` in the example below). Of course, it requires a means to stop the special collection process. Given your example, I decided that a line starting with `\explain` marks the end of this process (cf. `\listit@checknext`). Of course, one could use a different end marker if you wish.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487572/obeylines-and-gappto-from-etoolbox
%% Collect the body of the xltabular in \tabbody:
\begingroup
    \lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{%
\endgroup
    \long\def\tabline#1~{%
        \xappto{\tabbody}{\unexpanded{#1\\\hline}}%
        \futurelet\next\listit@checknext
    }
    \newcommand*{\listit@obeylines}{\catcode`~=\active \let~=\tabline}
}

\newcommand*{\listit@checknext}{%
   \ifx\next\explain
     \let\next=\relax
   \else
     \let\next=\tabline
   \fi
   \next
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{listit}{}{%
    \gdef\tabbody{}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \raggedcolumns
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \col@number\@ne
            \mathchardef\LT@end@pen=0 %
            \begingroup
                \listit@obeylines
}{%
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\explain}{}{%
            \endgroup
            \vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{X}
                \hline\hline
                \tabbody
                \hline\noalign{\vskip 4pt}%
            \end{xltabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{listit}
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt
\bfseries See Note
ut labore
\textbf{See Note}
magna aliqua.
Paragraph break here:\par But we remain in the same ``line.''
\explain

Note: \verb+\bfseries+ is not ignored anymore. You can easily see that
\verb+\textbf{See Note}+ works fine too.
\end{listit}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Footnote**

1. Such as a 〈letter〉, 〈otherchar〉 or `\unhbox` coming from the expansion of `\leavevmode`, among other possibilities (cf. TeXbook p. 283).